# Application name in data usage screen does not match Application Label

Tags: android

I am fetching data usage from `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)` and `TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)` and trying to build a report similar to the data usage screen present on stock android Settings.

When mapping back app's `uid` to names is where the confusion starts. `uid`s can be shared between apps and those apps may have different Application Labels. All that is understandable until you look at that screen and realize that some apps show a label that is none of the labels from the apps related to the `uid` but something else. **Where is this info coming from?**

Example, there are those 2 apps for UID 10015 with their following labels:

- UID: 10015
- Package: com.google.android.gms
- UID Name: com.google.uid.shared:10015 (`packageManager.getNameForUid(appInfo.uid)`)
- Application Label: Google Play Services (`packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo)`)

- UID: 10015,
- Package: com.google.android.gsf
- UID Name: com.google.uid.shared:10015
- Application Label: Google Services Framework

... and yet on the data usage screen I only see `Google Services` which does not match either.